# mongoDB in Ubuntu 20.04 Problems

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation

so i installed mongodb in a wrong way , like watched a video of it in youtube even if "mongo" command is working that doesn't mean its really working

so i'm trying to uninstall mongodb-org but i got this error :

```
sudo apt remove mongodb-org


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

when i tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-program-options1.71.0 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.6 mongo-tools mongodb-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 90.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 146 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-server amd64 4.4.1 [20.3 MB]
8% [1 mongodb-org-server 8,584 kB/20.3 MB 42%]                                                                                                            Get:2 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-mongos amd64 4.4.1 [15.7 MB]
Get:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4/multiverse amd64 mongodb-database-tools amd64 100.1.1 [54.4 MB]
Fetched 90.4 MB in 1min 11s (1,266 kB/s)                                                            
(Reading database ... 215423 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.4.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.
6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.4.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.
6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.1.1_amd64.deb (--un
pack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.1.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when trying this commands :

```
apt upgrade , autoclean,remove,purge
```

they give the same first error

i tried sudo apt clean , then sudo apt --fix-broken install the same problem happend and the same response

all i want is to remove it .

Answer (score 2):

In general if you are removing a package and you get that error, and you don't want the other packages that are being kept that want additional dependencies, you can remove all packages in the same command:

```
sudo apt remove mongodb-org mongodb-org-tools
```

Comment: mongo-tools or mongodb-org-tools? I was thought that this package https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/mongo-tools was a problem. Because of `mongodb-org-tools` is the name of this package for mongo v4 and this is the reason of conflict, because of it is a dependency of the virtual package `mongodb-org`

Comment: mongodb-org-tools depends on mongodb-database-tools if I am reading the output correctly. If there is a higher level mongodb-org that depends on -tools, the -org will get removed when -tools is removed. If not the -org can also be added to the remove list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with program:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/bsondump.1.html

that is installed in package: `mongo-tools` from mongo v3

You can try:

```
sudo apt remove mongo-tools
```

In docs you can read that in mongo v4 this package has name `mongodb-database-tools`

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/